# Find the multiplicative inverse of $\,x^2+(x^3-x+2)$ in the quotient $\,F_3[x]/(x^3-x+2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Find the multiplicative inverse of $x^2+(x^3-x+2)$ in the quotient $F_3[x]/(x^3-x+2)$ .

I've proved that $x^3-x+2$ is irreducible polynomial in $F_3[x]$, and that $x^2$ and $x^3-x+2$ are coprime integers, therefore gcd $(x^2, x^3-x+2)=1,$ and I can find $f,g$ in $F_3[x]$ such that:
$1 = f*x^2 + g*(x^3-x+2)$
when I take modulo $(x^3-x+2)$, I get: $1=f*x^2$ (every one of them with bar above to describe the modulo), it means that f is the multiplicative inverse and I need to find it.

By Gauss I tried to divide: $x^3-x+2 / x^2 = x*x^2 - x + 2$ and because we are in $F_3[x]$, I wrote $= x*x^2 + 2x+2$ , but I don't know how to continue from here, I got the "redundant" $2x+2$ and don't know how to get the multiplicative inverse...

Comment: Can you carry out the Euclidean Algorithm?

Comment: Isn't it what I did by Gauss? I'm confused..

Comment: You started. Need to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote you can find $f,g$ such that ... and that's what you need to do.
This is just th e(extended) Euclidean algorithm as known from integers, but requiring polynomial divisions.
Thius
$$\begin{align} x^3-x+2 &= x\cdot x^2 -(x-2)\\
 x^2 &=(x-2)\cdot x +2x\\
x-2 &= 2x\cdot \frac 12-2=2x\cdot  2+1\end{align}$$
(where only the last step is aware of us working in $\mathbb F_3$).
From this with $p(x)=x^3-x+2, q(x)=x^2$ we obtain step by step:
$$\begin{align}x-2 &= xq-p\\
2x &= q-x(xq-p)\\
1&=(xq-p)-2(q-x(xq-p))\end{align} $$
So
$$(x+2)\cdot p(x)+(2x^2+x+1)\cdot q(x) = 1$$